# Can a build hint variable be accessed from code in Codename One?

Tags: google-maps, codenameone

My app features a Google Map. I configured the build hints as mentionned [here on CN1 blog](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/new-improved-native-google-maps.html) with the slight difference that the Google Key was defined as a build hint variable as explained [here on CN1 blog](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/build-hint-variables.html).

Now in code I have to do `MapContainer map = new MapContainer(JAVASCRIPT_API_KEY);` which `JAVASCRIPT_API_KEY` is already defined in the build hints. Can I access to this build hint variable from code so that I don't have to include the `JAVASCRIPT_API_KEY` in code ? Does it bring anything regarding this key being encrypted and not appearing as plain text in the apk ?

Any help appreciated,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the build hints are a compile time feature. You can access them in the simulator for development purposes but in runtime on a device/web browser you won't be able to do that.

Usually I store the key in the server and just fetch it dynamically from there. I did it in the bootcamp and academy courses.

Comment: Thanks Shai for your quick reply. I have a look at the courses your are refering to!